# Jquery getJSON not firing controller method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I am trying to implement cascading dropdown list for which I have created following script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var district = $("#ddlDistrict");
            $('#ddlState').change(function () {
                //                district.find('option').remove();
                var cd = $(this).val();
                alert(cd);
                var url = '<!--Url.Content("~/")-->' + 'Stranger1/GetDistrict';
                $.getJSON("/Stranger1/GetDistrict?state="+cd, { id: cd }, function (data) {
                    //Clear the Department list
                    $("#ddlDistrict").empty();
                    $.each(data,function (index, optionData) {
                    $("#ddlDistrict").append("<option value=" + optionData.Value + ">" + optionData.Text + "</option>");
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

The alert(cd) is giving the correct value. But the second dropdown list is not showing the result and the getJSON method is not firing the GetDistrict method.

The lists in my view are:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlState", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["StateType"])
@Html.DropDownList("ddlDistrict",new List<SelectListItem>() )
```

Following is the controller:

```
public JsonResult GetDistrict(int id)
{
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult(); 
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> district = new SelectList(db.sp_get_district(id, 99).Select(r => new SelectListItem { Value = r.DISTRICT_CD.ToString(), Text = r.DISTRICT }), "value", "text");

    result.Data = district.ToList(); 
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet; 
    return result;   
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you not using the url variable?.Anyways if the directory is under the current dir there is no need /Stranger/GetDistrict.  Stranger1/GetDistrict will be enough

Answer (score 0):

Try editing to

$.getJSON("/Stranger1/GetDistrict?id="+cd, function (data)